# Python glob.glob returns empty list on Mac

Tags: python-3.x

I have folder full with different csv files which I would like to read, I used glob.glob on Windows and my code worked fine. 
I switched recently to Mac and when I used the same code it return empty list (with Spyder):

Windows code

```
data = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in glob.glob('C:/Data/*.csv')]
```

Mac code

```
data = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in glob.glob('~/Documents/Data/*.csv')]
```

Even if I remove the Tilda it return empty list in Mac

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) and then pass the resulting path to the `glob.glob`:

```
In [16]: os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/Data/*.csv')
Out[16]: '/Users/soon/Documents/Data/*.csv'
```